# How to Handle Incoming Messages in UCWA

Tags: javascript, node.js, object, skype, ucwa

I am trying to follow the following instructions (https://ucwa.skype.com/documentation/KeyTasks-Communication-IncomingIMCall) to handle incoming messages.

I don't have the "accept" href as there is already a conversation in progress (bot sends initial msg). I am trying to reply back and have the bot acknowledge the message I've sent.

The problem which I'm encountering is that while doing a console.log I can see that resources which I need exist in the event API response but when my code is executing it fails b/c it is undefined.

Here is a sample of the code:

```
    SkypeService.getEvent(msg).then(function (result) {
            msg.eventsNext = result._links.next.href;       
            if (result && result.sender && result.sender.length > 0) {
                if (result.sender) {
                    for (var item in result.sender) {
                        var ref = result.sender[item].events;
                        for (var key in ref) {
                            event = ref[key]._embedded;
                            messageIn.push(event);                                          
                        }                            
                    } 
                }
            }                   
            console.log(messageIn)
            if(link['rel'] == 'message') {
                            console.log("message is there")
                            if(embed.message) {
                                console.log("links exist")
                                if(embed.message.direction == "Incoming") {
                                    console.log("direction is there")
                                    msg.participant = embed.message._links.participant.href;
                                    msg.contMsg = embed.message._links.messaging.href;
                                    msg.msgIn = embed.message._links.plainMessage.href;
                                }
                            }
                        }
```

The undefined returns for where I am calling the condition to check direction.

The objective of the above code is to get the incoming message and the applicable href to send a reply back.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You should really switch how your code is handling the events you find in the events array.  You can check the existence of the **rel** property for some resources and handle them accordingly or for **message** you need to look for link and check that **rel**.  I don't know why the additional complication but your above code can fail to execute because you are accessing objects without checking:

`messageIn[i].messagingInvitation.direction` - messagingInvitation might be null
`messageIn[i].message.direction` - message might be null
`messageIn[i].messaging.state` - messaging might be null

Comment: @ShelbyZ Thanks for the input. I have changed my code so that it does this check on the rel. However, I am having similar issues where I can see that direction incoming exists in Postman but it is not finding it while executing my code. It is a hit/miss scenario...sometimes it does and other times it doesn't. Please see the updated code above.